# Adding a space to a resx language value

Tags: resource-files

I want to add a space between two words in a language resx file where I am translating from English to Afrikaans/Dutch, specifically for an input placeholder field. The problem I'm having is when I run the cshtml page, the words after the space don't show. The only way they do show is if I remove the spaces from the resx value field. Is there a way to have a space and show the whole sentence (with spaces) in the value field

[image: Example of the language resx file with values]

Is there a way for the space to be included in the value field and show up in the input placeholder field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to this question I asked: In the placeholder field where the the field is referenced, add the name field in inverted commas. 
E.g. `placeholder="resources.languages.sales_order_item_details";`
This removed spaces after the first space